# Encoding bug with the teamslogon.aspx redirection service

Tags: microsoft-teams

Since last week, there seems to be a new bug with the teamslogon.aspx redirection service.
It seems to double encode the provided url, redirecting to an invalid url and resulting in a 404.

Exemple:

```
https://contoso.sharepoint.com/sites/ContosoNet/_layouts/15/teamslogon.aspx?SPFX=true&dest=/sites/ContosoNet/Home%20page.aspx
```

will redirect to

```
https://contoso.sharepoint.com/sites/ContosoNet/Home%2520page.aspx
```

See the double encoding with the "Home%2520page" above.

The impact is that you can no longer provide to the teamslogon.aspx an url containing a space or any special character.
This will result in a redirect to an invalid url and a 404.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you for the insights on the document. I am able to reproduce the issue, I have raised a [bug](https://github.com/SharePoint/sp-dev-docs/issues/6776) and concern team is working on it.